# Is ping not supposed to work via proxychains?

Tags: ping

The `ping` program being the implementation of ICMP protocol (and it being based on raw sockets instead of TCP or UDP sockets), **I'm not sure** if it is supposed to work via a program like `proxychains`.

For example, when I try the following, the program remains hung forever until I `Ctrl-C` it:

```
[root@hostA tmp]# proxychains ping www.google.com
ProxyChains-3.1 (http://proxychains.sf.net)
|DNS-request| www.google.com 
|S-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:4000-<><>-4.2.2.2:53-<><>-OK
|DNS-response| www.google.com is 209.85.175.103
PING  (209.85.175.103) 56(84) bytes of data.

   ( ***** HUNG HERE FOREVER! ***** )
```

However, a program like `curl` works just fine:

```
[root@hostA tmp]# proxychains curl http://thin.npr.org > page.html
|DNS-request| thin.npr.org 
|S-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:4000-<><>-4.2.2.2:53-<><>-OK
|DNS-response| thin.npr.org is 216.35.221.76
|S-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:4000-<><>-216.35.221.76:80-<><>-OK
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  2295  100  2295    0     0    284      0  0:00:08  0:00:08 --:--:--   565

[root@hostA tmp]# ls -l page.html 
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 2339 Jun 29 17:37 page.html
```

Note also that I can `ping www.google.com` fine from another Internet-enabled machine without using `proxychains`. In other words, `www.google.com` seems very much to be a `ping`-able server.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I guess not. If you have a look at http://proxychains.sourceforge.net/ it explicitly states it supports TCP and DNS (which actually can be UDP or TCP)

You can find a similar answer to it here: http://www.backtrack-linux.org/wiki/index.php/Proxychains

In general proxies don't support ICMP traffic. Neither does Proxychains